# Confirm alert before close the window

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <form>
           .....
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
       </form>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
        function confirmExit()
        {
            return "...";
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

I want to confirm only when I click the browser X not when I submit the form. What change? Is possible?

Comment: In my case that solution did not work. I have tried it.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? You need to provide more details then.

Comment: when I click on submit my confirmation appears. When I click submit button I want reload without confirmation, the other post only change the confirm text. I think is a different question. It isn't a duplicate question